# Kotlin Generics: Kotlin does not recognize my class with correct inheritance

Tags: generics, kotlin, variance

this is my simplified example:

```
interface IMyView

interface IMyViewModel<VIEW : IMyView, in ITEM> {

    fun attachView(view: VIEW)

    fun getView(): VIEW?
}


class myView : IMyView

class MyViewModel : IMyViewModel<myView, String> {
    override fun attachView(view: myView) {
        TODO("not implemented")
    }

    override fun getView(): myView? {
        TODO("not implemented")
    }
}


abstract class MyBaseClass<VIEWMODEL : IMyViewModel<out IMyView, *>> : IMyView {

    protected lateinit var viewModel: VIEWMODEL

    fun myInvocation(): Unit {
        viewModel.attachView(this as IMyView)
    }
}

class MyMainClass : MyBaseClass<MyViewModel>()
```

The problem is the last line, because MyViewModel is not recognized as IMyViewModel. Error message is as follows:

```
Type argument is not within its bounds. 
Expected: IMyViewModel<IMyView, *>
Found: MyViewModel
```

In Java it works. What I have to adapt to make it workable in Kotlin as well?

****** update ******

If you use

```
abstract class MyBaseClass<VIEWMODEL : IMyViewModel<out IMyView, *>>
```

(please see updated Kotlin code above)

then I cannot call myInvocation because for that call I need 'in IMyView'.
Therefore it is a disaster. All what I do results in other problems. That was easier in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem now. I made a concept error. Here is the solution:

```
interface IMyViewModel<VIEW : IMyView, in ITEM> {

    fun attachView(view: VIEW)

    fun getView(): VIEW?
}


class MyViewModel : IMyViewModel<IMyView, String> {
    override fun attachView(view: IMyView) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun getView(): IMyView? {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}


abstract class MyBaseClass<VIEWMODEL : IMyViewModel<IMyView, *>> : IMyView {

    protected lateinit var viewModel: VIEWMODEL

    fun myInvocation(): Unit {
        viewModel.attachView(this)
    }
}

class MyMainClass : MyBaseClass<MyViewModel>()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that when you make an upper bound `VIEWMODEL : IMyViewModel<IMyView, *>`, a type can satisfy this bound **only** if it implements `IMyViewModel` with the `VIEW` type parameter substituted **exactly** with `IMyView`, no subtype of `IMyView` is allowed (and thus `MyViewModel` is rejected). In other words, [`VIEW` is invariant](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance).

Since Kotlin allows you to specify the type parameter variance both at declaration site and at use site, you can fix this by doing one of the following:

- Make the `VIEW` type parameter of `IMyViewModel` covariant with declaration-site variance:

  ```
  interface IMyViewModel<out VIEW : IMyView, in ITEM>  
                         ^^^
  ```
- Add an `out`-projection at the use-site of `IMyViewModel` in the `VIEWMODEL` upper bound:

  ```
  abstract class MyBaseClass<VIEWMODEL : IMyViewModel<out IMyView, *>>
                                                      ^^^
  ```
- Add another type parameter `T` to `MyBaseClass` and use it in `IMyViewModel<T, *>`:

  ```
  abstract class MyBaseClass<T : IMyView, VIEWMODEL : IMyViewModel<T, *>>
  class MyMainClass: MyBaseClass<myView, MyViewModel>()
  ```

Comment: You are right, that works then. But I have the additional problem that IMyViewModel has two fun's:   fun attachView(view: VIEW), fun getView(): VIEW? The fun attachView(view: VIEW) will not work with out, because it is an In there. What can I do?

Comment: @grenzfrequence, then you can only apply the use-site variance, and you won't be able to safely call `attachView(view: VIEW)`, because `VIEW` will have no lower bound (it can be any subtype of `IMyView`). If that does not fit your use case, you can try to add another type parameter to `MyBaseClass`, please see the updated answer.

Comment: @grenzfrequence, I've checked the question update, and seems like the last point in the updated answer solves the problem.

Comment: I just updated my code. Your approach does not work for me, because if you declare interface IMyViewModel<out View : IMyView, in ITEM>, then the compiler describes for fun attachView(view: VIEW) in IMyViewModl as follows: "The type parameter is desclared as 'out' but occurs in 'in' position in type VIEW.

Comment: please copy and paste that code in Android Studio and you will see immediately the error message when you chance the code with 'out'.

Comment: @grenzfrequence, did you try the third point I added after your comment (the one suggesting to add another type parameter `T`)? It works for me on the full code sample from the updated answer.

Comment: the third point does not work for me because MyBaseClass itself is the view what I want to set with attachView. Therefore I will not use a view from outside.